# Opencart - Undefined variable in new shipping module

Tags: php, html, opencart

I'm making a new shipping module for opencart. Which simply takes the name and cost from the admin. But, shows an error inside the textbox.
[image: Undefined Variable]

I'm stuck in here, Really want solution. My view (.tpl) file is given below.

```
  <div class="box">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1><img src="view/image/shipping.png" alt="" /> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <div class="buttons"><a onclick="$('#form').submit();" class="button"><?php echo $button_save; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $button_cancel; ?></a></div>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
        <table class="form">

          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_name; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ndz_name" value="<?php echo $ndz_name; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_amount; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ndz_amount" value="<?php echo $ndz_amount; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_status; ?></td>
            <td><select name="ndz_status">
                <?php if ($ndz_status) { ?>
                <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_sort_order; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ndz_sort_order" value="<?php echo $ndz_sort_order; ?>" size="1" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Opencart version : 1.5

Comment: Ar you setting these variables in controller?

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to initialize your `$ndz_name` and `$ndz_amount` before you echos it.

```
$ndz_name = '';
$ndz_amount = '';
if (!empty($_POST["ndz_name"])) {
    $ndz_name = $_POST["ndz_name"];
}
if (!empty($_POST["ndz_amount"])) {
    $ndz_amount = $_POST["ndz_amount"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already cleared the error myself and i accepted it anyway. But, now i'm having another problem. when i proceed to checkout with my new shipping module it shows "Warning: Shipping method required!". Any ideas?

Comment: please create another question for another problem, and post the relevant code there. but i think, this is because you do a check on your shipping method, and there is no value for that.